# symfony2 translating data into other languages (internationalization and localization)

Tags: php, symfony

working on a symfony2 [multi-tenant architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitenancy) project(multiple users with dedicated customizable front end), where there  are multiple clients with seperate assets in seperate folders, subdomains are used to differentiate between the clients and the corrosponding data and assets are loaded depending on the client, this being the setup how would i go about having different languages for each client, eg: client 1 would like to have his website in english and spanish, client 2 would like it in english and french.

- how does symfony handle internationalization

under the App > Resources > Translations i could have different messages.yml but how will i differentiate between them (client 1's messages.en.yml and client 2's messages.en.yml) and how will i load it dynamically

- how do i load only specific translation files dynamically

Comment: Look at this: http://www.webtipblog.com/extend-symfony-2-translator-to-log-untranslated-messages-to-a-database/

Comment: @malcolm the RosettaBundle mentioned in the blog looks promising

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you properly, you want let to user to consider language for displaying you site, right?

If, yes, Symfony provide powerfull mechanism for i18n:
In `configuration.yml` add:

```
framework:
    translator:      { fallback: "%locale%" }
    default_locale:  "%locale%"
```

Then in `routing.yml` import you routes:

```
main:
  resource: "@MyAwesomeBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
  prefix:   /{_locale}
  requirements:
    _locale: |uk|en
  defaults: { _locale: en }
```

More info you can get [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/translation.html). And if you want to store you translations in Database you should look to [DoctrineExtensionsBundle](https://github.com/stof/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle). Hope it will help.